# Tradução de «feedback» para Português

Tags: termos-em-inglês

Na utilização oral, ouve-se muito

> Depois dá-me algum *feedback*.

Qual é a palavra portuguesa mais adequada para descrever esse conceito? Ou seja, como se poderia dizer o mesmo, usando apenas termos da língua portuguesa?

Comment: Gosto da opção "retorno".

Comment: "Feedback" é um estrangeirismo sólido no PB e passou a ser utilizado tanto em textos orais como escritos devido a sua especificidade, quando comparado com suas traduções: "comentário" e "opinião".

Comment: @Diego, Se é sólido, não devia.

Comment: É possível traduzir, mas "feedback" é um conceito e, portanto, não deveria ser reduzido a uma mera tradução. Essencialmente, é a obtenção de uma resposta, uma avaliação. "Comentário" e "opinião" convergem para esse sentido, embora não sejam completamente equivalentes.

Comment: @Diego esse conceito é perfeitamente enquadrável na língua Portuguesa, consoante o contexto. Tem alguma coisa contra a palavra "retorno"?

Comment: Não, "retorno" pode ser aplicável desde que obedeça estritamente o contexto linguístico: "Quando o senhor vai dar o retorno (feedback) dos quatro capítulos de minha dissertação?"

Comment: @Diego claro, foi o que referi

Comment: Informação de resposta, de retorno.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [**Feedback**](http://www.significados.com.br/feedback/) é uma palavra inglesa que significa realimentar ou dar resposta a uma determinado pedido ou acontecimento. O termo é utilizado em áreas como Administração de Empresas, Psicologia ou Engenharia Elétrica.

Em textos técnicos de **medicina, psicologia, engenharia ou administração de  empresas**, "feedback" pode ser traduzido como:

- Realimentação;
- Retroalimentação;
- Ou retroação.

Já quando usado como no exemplo "**dá-me algum *feedback***", dependendo do contexto geral poderíamos traduzir por:

- Opinião;
- Retorno;
- Comentário;
- Informação;
- Ou resposta.

Em pt-BR é comum ouvirmos: "faça conforme eu lhe expliquei e depois dê-me um retorno", "Podes deixar que, no mais tardar até quarta-feira, eu te dou um retorno a respeito". No entanto, está se tornando cada mais comum ouvirmos a palavra não traduzida como em "eu te dou um feedback a respeito".

> - Apresentei o meu relatório para os acionistas e o feedback foi muito positivo.

Comment: _retroalimentação_ é a mais comum em engenharia electrotécnica. Realimentação e retroação nunca encontrei.

Comment: @Artefacto  Em medicina usa-se retroalimentação positiva e negativa, em relação à interação entre hipófise e glândulas por ela comandadas.

Comment: Já ouvi também "devolutiva".

Comment: Apesar de ter colocado esta resposta como solução, considero, que tirando o campo da engenharia ou ciência, ou seja, para o exemplo em apreço, a palavra **retorno**, é que de forma cristalina mais se adequa. Explicações [aqui](http://www.veraveritas.eu/2016/05/em-portugues-feedback-e-retorno.html) .

Comment: estive a reler e merece +1

Comment: O Michaelis e Dicionário Unesp já registram "feedback" como estrangeirismo consolidado no PB, ou seja, passou a integrar o vernáculo como qualquer outra palavra.

Answer (score 0):

Um poblema com a tradução de *feedback* é o mesmo com muitas palavras em inglês, que carregam em si várias nuances em uma só palavra (à semelhança de *stress*); então obviamente a tradução mais adequada dependerá muito do contexto.
Um outro problema é o que eu gostaria de agregar ao que já foi dito. Mesmo quando neologismos no próprio inglês, estas palavras rapidamente atravessam diversas áreas e registros (âmbitos) de linguagem. Por exemplo, no corredor de uma empresa se falaria "Me dê um retorno quando puder", mas (1) este "retorno" é informal e (2) feedback não carrega o sentido físico que a palavra retorno pode ter em outro contexto em português (como em retorno e devolução). Isto se torna um desafio ao traduzir fragmentos mais curtos de texto, como titulos/cabeçalhos. Então o termo *parecer* (substantivo) seria muito adequado em contextos formais empresariais e técnicos (sempre que não se referir ao feedback científico já mencionado, que pode ser traduzido como retroalimentação).

Comment: Poblema? Um bicho estranho....:) Me dê um retorno, pode ser: get back to me, também. e não implica feedback. Feedback é você le algo e depois comentar o que foi lido em outro texto ou verbalmente.