# Tradução de "trade-off" para português

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia, termos-em-inglês

Sou estatístico e, frequentemente, preciso usar esse termo por não conseguir encontrar, em Português, um termo que consiga trazer todas as conotações que esse anglicismo possui.  Por exemplo, posso falar em um *trade-off* entre a complexidade de um modelo e a sua capacidade de explicação do comportamento observado, sem ter um termo em português que expresse essa mesma ideia tão bem.

Em linhas próximas à [desta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3191/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-feedback-para-portugu%C3%AAs), eu gostaria de saber se vocês têm boas alternativas para esse estrangeirismo.

Comment: Pois, partilho do teu problema (sou economista).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Compromisso

Repara que o  inglês *compromise* também tem este significado ([1.1 no *Oxford Dictionaries*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/compromise)).

Exemplos do CETEMPúblico:

> *par=ext1173-soc-93b-1*: Sacrificíos com origem na flexibilidade das relações de trabalho, na moderação salarial; na articulação entre a política fiscal e social, baseada num ***compromisso** entre a criação de novos empregos e a protecção social*.
>
> *par=ext88136-clt-soc-94a-2*: A sua distância focal (F = 900 mm) , embora obrigue a um comprimento razoável do tubo, constitui a solução mais comum para este tipo de instrumentos, em que é preciso estabelecer um ***compromisso** entre a definição das imagens e o comprimento físico do telescópio*.